# Not IN equivalent in XPath expression

Tags: xslt, xpath

I am working on an XSL development and I am in need of knowing the NOT IN equivalent in XPATH. 
I am presenting the XML and XSL in the simplest format which would be understandable to all.

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="XSL.xsl"?>
<Message>
    <Customers>
        <Customer pin="06067">1</Customer>
        <Customer pin="06068">2</Customer>
        <Customer pin="06069">3</Customer>
        <Customer pin="06070">4</Customer>
        <Customer pin="06072">5</Customer>
    </Customers>
    <Addresses>
        <Address pin1="06067">A</Address>
        <Address pin1="06068">B</Address>
        <Address pin1="06069">C</Address>
    </Addresses>
</Message>
```

XSL

```
<xsl:template match="/Message">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h4>Existing Customers</h4>
            <table>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//Customers/Customer[@pin = //Addresses/Address/@pin1]"></xsl:apply-templates>
            </table>

            <h4>New Customers</h4>
            <table>
                <!--This place need to be filled with new customers-->
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Customer" name="Customer">
    <xsl:variable name="pin" select="./@pin"></xsl:variable>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:text> is in </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="//Addresses/Address[@pin1=$pin]"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

In the above XSLT, under the commented area, i need to match and display the customers who's address is not existing in the Addresses/Address node.

Please help find an XPath expression that would match the Customers who are NOT IN the Addresses Node set. (Any alternate could also help)

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for an efficient, short and simple XSLT solution. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In XPath 1.0:

```
/Message/Customers/Customer[not(@pin=/Message/Addresses/Address/@pin1)]
```

Comment: +1. This is fundamental XPath knowledge -- unfortunately the OP is happy that "it works" and would probably not delve further to understand what actually is happening... :(

Comment: I think the fundamental what-is-happening that @Dimitre refers to is the fact that the "=" operator is an "existentially quantified comparison" operator, that is, `A = B` tells you whether there is a pair of values, one in nodeset A and one in nodeset B, that are equal to each other. In the above example, A is @pin which addresses only one node (because it is in the context of just one `Customer`), while the B path addresses many nodes.

Answer (score 4):

**An alternative to the good answer by @Alejandro**, which I upvoted, is the following transformation, which uses keys and **will be more efficient if the number of existing customers is big**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="kexistingByPin"
         match="Address" use="@pin1"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:apply-templates select=
    "*/*/Customer[not(key('kexistingByPin', @pin))]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Message>
    <Customers>
        <Customer pin="06067">1</Customer>
        <Customer pin="06068">2</Customer>
        <Customer pin="06069">3</Customer>
        <Customer pin="06070">4</Customer>
        <Customer pin="06072">5</Customer>
    </Customers>
    <Addresses>
        <Address pin1="06067">A</Address>
        <Address pin1="06068">B</Address>
        <Address pin1="06069">C</Address>
    </Addresses>
</Message>
```

**the wanted, correct answer is produced**:

```
<Customer pin="06070">4</Customer>
<Customer pin="06072">5</Customer>
```